# Combination of ng-repeat and ng-options angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

My goal is to let the user re-orders an array of image by choosing the position for each image in the array. For each of them, I have a ng-repeat that displays the image, and also a select dropdown button where the user can select the index for each image depending of the length of $scope.stock.otherPicNames.

HTML :

```
 <div class="gallery_wrapper" ng-repeat="f in stock.otherPicNames"> 
    <img ng-src="{{getImage(f)}}"> 
    <div class="order_gallery"> 
        <select ng-options="pos as obj.position for obj in position track by $index" ng-value="$index+1 " ng-model="f.position"></select>
     </div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
$scope.position = [];
$scope.choice = [];

angular.forEach($scope.stock.otherPicNames, function(image){
        $scope.position.push({'image' : image, 'position' : 0 });
        $scope.choice.push(0);
});
```

I'm stuck in getting back the value selected by the user and put it inside $scope.choice array or $scope.position.position depending on each image. I don't know how to set correctly  ng-options and ng-value.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Do the images already have a position number?  What is being used for sorting the images to start?

Comment: @RaniRadcliff Hello, they don't. By default the position number of each image depends on its positions on the array. There is no sort at the beginning, I just get my image array from my server.  With this junk of code, the user is able to change the position of each image.